# Filter search by book page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there a module or some sort of native functionality available in Drupal that will allow search filtration by book page? (e.g. limit search to a particular section in the book)

Or some easy way to attach taxonomy to a book using page titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this module http://drupal.org/project/rules, with help of it you can create special set of actions when some action was performed in drupal, in your case this is 'Node created'. For example you can create new taxonomy term from title of a book page and then attach this new term to created page. Try it, Rules module can easy solve many problems like yours.

Comment: Excellent, this seems like it could help with a lot of problems. Thanks!